# last iterated value is coming in all objects

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic2, google-cloud-firestore

I am iterating a collection doc and a sub-iteration for each parent iteration item.

```
public getxxxxxTimings(key : string) : any {

    console.log('key '+key);
    return this.afs.collection('/xxxxx/'+key+'/slots').doc('1').ref.get().then((doc)=>{

        let json = doc.data();
        console.log('json data '+json);
        console.log("Document keys:", Object.keys(json));
        Object.keys(json).forEach((name) => {
            this.timingRef = new Timing();
            console.log('name '+name);
            this.timingRef.slot = name;
            this.timingRef.available = json[name];
            this.afs.collection('/slots/').doc(name).ref.get().then((doc)=>{
                let json2 = doc.data();
                console.log('json data '+json2);
                console.log("Document keys:", Object.keys(json2));
                Object.keys(json2).forEach((name2) => {

                    if(name2 == 'from'){
                        this.timingRef.from = json2[name2];
                    }
                    else{
                        this.timingRef.to = json2[name2];
                    }

                })

                console.log('Timings count '+this.Timings.push(this.timingRef));

            })

        })

        return this.Timings;


    });



  }
```

In the above code, the parent loop is preparing an object in each iteration and pushing it to the collection.
The problem is, all the objects are getting filled with lastly iterated values where as logs are showing as expected.

```
key -KiDPBvL9xG7_hAQ0kpv
timingmodal.ts:29 key -KiDPBvL9xG7_hAQ0kpv
user-service.ts:119 key -KiDPBvL9xG7_hAQ0kpv
timingmodal.ts:38 ionViewDidLoad TimingmodalPage
user-service.ts:123 json data [object Object]
user-service.ts:124 Document keys: (4) ["1", "2", "3", "5"]
user-service.ts:127 name 1
user-service.ts:127 name 2
user-service.ts:127 name 3
user-service.ts:127 name 5
user-service.ts:132 json data [object Object]
user-service.ts:133 Document keys: (2) ["from", "to"]
user-service.ts:145 Timings count 1
user-service.ts:132 json data [object Object]
user-service.ts:133 Document keys: (2) ["from", "to"]
user-service.ts:145 Timings count 2
user-service.ts:132 json data [object Object]
user-service.ts:133 Document keys: (2) ["from", "to"]
user-service.ts:145 Timings count 3
user-service.ts:132 json data [object Object]
user-service.ts:133 Document keys: (2) ["from", "to"]
user-service.ts:145 Timings count 4
```

The UI is written as

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let timing of Timings | async">
    {{ timing.slot }} -{{ timing.from }} -- {{ timing.to }}-- {{ timing.available }} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

The values are rendered like below.

[image]

Ideally, it should be like..

1-9-10--true

2-10-11--true

3-11-12--false

5-13-14--true

What I am missing here, please advise.

Comment: Your array only contains `this.timingRef`, which has pushed in many times. That means each time you change one of the properties, you changing every copy within that array

Comment: @user184994 I'm assigning new object in each iteration right as "this.timingRef = new Timing()"

Comment: From looking at those logs, `name` 1 - 4 are printed underneath each other, then your `Timing count` logs, so by the time it's doing the push, they're all using the latest copy of `timingRef`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked and rendering correctly after replacing the global `timingRef` object with the local reference.

```
this.timingRef = new Timing(); => let timingRef = new Timing();
```

Thanks for user184994 as his/her comment gave me a hint to think of it.